# mySQL to PHP to jQuery returning floating point value as string (JSON)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, floating-point

I am new to PHP, jQuery and SQL, and I am trying to return data from my database to be used in my javascript file.  For some reason, my object is being returned as a string even though values should be floating point numbers.

My database structure has this column setup to be a floating point number.

Here is a segment of my PHP code:

```
$q = "SELECT object FROM $tableName";

if($q === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}

$sth = mysqli_query ($con, $q);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
    }

print json_encode($rows);
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$.get('PHP file URL', function(data) {

    var object = JSON.parse(data);
```

However, I am getting the following (a string) returned instead of a floating point number:

```
[{"object":"34.416"},{"object":"34.589"},{"object":"33.3948"}]
```

I can't seem to find this same issue already posted.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Everything that comes from MySQL is of type string. You want to cast to float before ecoding to json.

Comment: I tried casting to float in the SQL SELECT statement, but that only gave an error on the mysql_fetch_assoc line in PHP.  Are you saying I should cast to float in javascript?

Comment: You should cast in php when you iterate over the resultset.

Comment: Ok, great.  I'll research that and see what I can do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two choices

```
$q = "SELECT object FROM $tableName";

if($q === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}

$sth = mysqli_query ($con, $q);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = array('object'=> (float)$r['object'];
    }

print json_encode($rows);
```

or in jquery

```
$.get('PHP file URL', function(data) {
    var object = [];
    $.each(data, function(){
         object.push(parseFloat(this.object))
    });

    var object = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, because I couldn't get the jquery version to work, but the PHP one did work, which is probably more efficient anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: A follow-up question would be:  what if I want to SELECT more than one column from the database?  Since I am defining which column to convert in the $rows[] = array('object'=> (float)$r['object']; line, it only converts that column.  I tried adding another line like that, but it gave that column a value of 0.  Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out.  I'll add it to your answer.

Comment: Not sure why my improvements to the answer are not approved for posting.  Here is the complete answer for converting multiple columns in one JSON object:  $rows[] = array('object01'=> (float)$r['object01'], 'object02'=> (float)$r['object02']);

Answer (score 0):

the quick fix would be , to alter column option from unsigned ZeroFill to empty.